# Correct way to implement a REST API using MVC

Tags: node.js, api, rest, crud

### Summary

I am seeing a lot of contradictory architectural examples of a REST API in my work and keep getting different opinions on the subject.

I am familiar with the principles of REST and seeing as each endpoint points to a resource followed by a verb such as `/project/create` `project/123/read`.

Following the MVC pattern assuming I have a controller that is responsible for updating a project resource:

`router.put("/project/:id/update", ProjectController.put)`

#### First question:

Should this route be responsible for all updates to this resource, in example, assuming different features on my client like marking a project as finished or changing it's title are separated and might not have anything in common for the user. Ending up with the route described above, or should there be something like this:

`router.put("/project/:id/mark-as-done", ProjectController.markAsDone)`

`router.put("/project/:id/update-info", ProjectController.updateInfo)`

#### Second question:

Assuming I want to create a **notification** resource if a **project** is created/updated/deleted. Since the **notification** is a resource on it's own I am not sure how to go about this, but what I assumed and was taught is to use another callback:

`router.put("/project/:id/update", ProjectController.put, NotificationController.create)`

#### Third question:

Could I use the same controller to read all resources or just one, for example:

`router.get("/project/read", ProjectController.get)`

`router.get("/project/:id/read", ProjectController.get)`

Making the logic in the controller method determinate if it will return all projects or just one. Or should it be separated into different methods?

Answer (score 1):

I would define APIs like this:-

#### CRUD for Project entity

- create- router.post(/projects)
- update:- router.put(/projects/:id)
- delete:- router.delete(/projects/:id)
- read:- router.get(/projects) and/or  router.get(/projects/:id)

  You can define all above routes in ProjectController.

#### Regarding Notification entity you can define as follows

- read:- router.get(/projects/:id/notifications)
- The same can be applied to PUT, DELETE, POST

Here is a good article defining rest guidelines https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/